# Application Context destroyed and SessionFactory as well

Tags: spring, destroy

I am working on a web application which comprising of Spring 3 , Hibernate ( annotation based ) and Apapache CXF.

I am getting some weird problem, when web server ( tomcat ) load the context, all the beans get loaded through spring container but then immediately spring container start destroying those loaded beans....I am getting exception something like

> DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(422) | Destroying singletons in  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@744589eb: defining  beans ( list of beans that are then destroyed ).

Immediately and after this, I do get a message that ([ERROR]

> ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(227) | Context initialization failed)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(HibernateDaoSupport.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
>       ... 36 more

I dont really know why container destroying the beans.

Can somebody please help me resolve this weird problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's doing that because it can't start due to a configuration problem. Fix the problem (See the exception that you pasted in the question: `'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required`) and it should start.